# Laravel 5.2: Opening different tabs of the same user

Tags: database, laravel

I am trying to match the User id, with the user id already saved in the database, so that if it matches then show the different details of the user. But it is showing error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161
```

Also, I want to open different details of the user as soon as the user id matches, but it's not working either. When I tried it without the welcome page, and just writing the user_id in the URL, it was showing the first tab, but when I click on the second tab, it shows error. Details and official are the tabs on navigation bar and functions also.

welcome blade.php:

```
<form action="action_page.php">
    Enter user id:
    <input type="number" name="user_id">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

UserController:

```
public function getUser(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['user_id' => $user_id]))  {

        return redirect()->route('pages.Details');
    }

        return redirect()->back();   
}


public function getPD($user_id)
{
    $user = User::Find($user_id);
    return view('pages.Details')->withUser($user);
}

public function getOD($user_id)
{
    $user = User::Find($user_id);
    return view('pages.Official')->withUser($user);
}
```

User model:

```
protected $table = 'tbl_user';
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/User',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@getUser',
    'as'   => 'getUser'
    ]);

Route::get('/PD',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@getPD',
    'as'   => 'PD'
    ]);
```

I tried many ways, but it's not working.Please tell me how to do it. any suggestions are welcome.

How can I allow the user to match it's user id from the database, and then show it's the details by making the details tab first to appear, and when the user click on the official tab, it will show that table.

Comment: Your are not follow laravel structure. Go to the laravel Docs and see how to work this.

Comment: Please can you tell me Where am i not following laravel structure?

Comment: https://laravel.com/

Answer (score 0):

Auth:attemp() is used to authenticate user and not to get the user. If you want to get the user by id you need to change this function:

```
public function getUser(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['user_id' => $user_id]))  {

        return redirect()->route('pages.Details');
    }

        return redirect()->back();   
}
```

to:

```
public function getUser(Request $request)
{
    $userid= $request['user_id'];
    $user = App\User::find($userid);
    return redirect()->route('pages.Details')->with('user',$user);
}
```

and use `$user` in your details template.

Answer (score 0):

From your `getUser()` method, it looks like you want to redirect an authenticated user to a different page than an unauthenticated user. Here's what you can do to achieve that:

welcome.blade.php

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('getUser') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <label for="user_id_input" >Enter user id:</label>
    <input type="number" id="user_id_input" name="user_id" value="{{ old('user_id') }}>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/user',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@getUser',
    'as'   => 'getUser'
]);

Route::get('/PD',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@getPD',
    'as'   => 'PD'
]);
```

UserController.php

```
public function getUser(Request $request)
{
    $user_id= $request->get('user_id');

    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id === $user_id){
        return redirect()->route('PD');
    }

    return back()->withInput();;
}

public function getPD($user_id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
    return view( 'pages.Details', compact('user') );
}

public function getOD($user_id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
    return view( 'pages.Official', compact('user') );
}
```

Views file structure

```
-views
    -pages
        -Details.blade.php
        -Official.blade.php
    -welcome.blade.php
```

Use `$user` in your Details.blade.php file.